# How to display SQL query using Group by like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

2i ll listed only 1 table that i need to query :

lodgings_Contract :

```
id_contract     indentity primary,    
id_person       int,   
id_room         varchar(4),   
day_begin       datetime,   
day_end         datetime,
day_register    datetime  
money_per_month money
```

And this is values for table lodgings_Contract (This datas used for Example only):

```
id_contract | id_person | id_room | day_begin -----|  day_end ----- | day_register------- | money_per_month

          3 |      2 |   101 | 1/12/2014  | 27/2/2015 |   1/12/2015   |       100
          2 |      1 |   102 | 1/1/2014   | 27/4/2014 |   1/1/2014    |       200
          1 |      3 |   103 | 1/1/2014   | 27/3/2014 |   1/1/2014    |       300
```

*person 1 rent room 102 in 4 month at year 2014 with 200/month And person 2 rent room 101 in 3 month but 1 month at year 2014 and 2 month at year 2015 with 100/month .Person 3 rent room 103 in 3 month at year 2014 with 300/month

I want my result display 3 field : Month | Year | Incomes

Result :

Month |  Year  | Incomes

> ```
> 1  |2014|  500
> 2  |2014|  500
> 3  |2014|  500
> 4  |2014|  200
> 12 |2014|  100
> 1  |2015|  100
> 2  |2015|  100
> ```

Can i do that ? Help me Please !

I was post another post before this post but it complicated and requires 3 tables so i make this post with only 1 table.

This is my code :

```
select month(day_begin)as 'Month',year(day_begin)as 'Year',money_per_month as 'Incomes'
from lodgings_Contract
group by day_begi,money_per_month
```

It only listed first month of "day_begin".I have no idea how to do it right

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to caculate "incomes" every month of year using group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583942/how-to-caculate-incomes-every-month-of-year-using-group-by)

Comment: yes but that post my data is not clearly that make people think wrong then can i do another post (this) ?

Comment: Please show your effort. From the About page: "Include details about what you have tried".

Comment: You can edit the old question to made you point clear, or you can delete the old one and write a new one (this one). Right now the only difference is that you want the result divideds in month instead of years

Comment: i was deleted old question

Comment: This is tagged as both sql-server and mysql. Which is it?

Comment: What is the logic for `Incomes` column? Is it month' total?

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Is [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bf41e/2) what you want? If not, please explain.

Comment: No it is not what i want . I want my result like my post at top . "incomes" column is Sum(money_per_month) . I ll explain like this : person 1 rent room 102 in 4 month at year 2014 with 200/month .That means each month in that Contract from day he go in(day_begin) to day he left(day_end) i ll got 200/eachmont (month 1->month 4) of that year 2014.At the same time person 3 rent room 103 in 3 month(from month 1-> month 3) with 300/month.That mean at month 1 to month 3 year 2014 money i earned is (money_per_month of person 2 + money_per_month of  person 3 )=500.

Comment: And now person 3 end Contract with me then he leaved ,but Person 2 still have Contract with me to month 4 year 2014.that mean my result "Incomes" have 500from month 1 -> month 3,and 200 at month 4 year 2014.From month 4 to month 11 i don't make any contract until Person 1 maked Contract with me he rent room 101 from month 12 year 2014 to month 2 year 2015.He rent room 101 in 3 month but 1 month at year 2014 and 2 month at year 2015 with 100 / month.Now my result is : month 1-3 year 2014 =500/month,month 4 year 2014 =200,month 12/2014=100 and month 1/2015=100,month 2/2015=100

Comment: i using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you first need a calendar table, in the following query is created on the fly with a CTE.
That said what is the purpose of the column day_register? It seems a copy of day_begin, with probably a typo for the contract with ID 3.

```
WITH Months(N) AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL Select 2 UNION ALL Select 3 UNION ALL Select 4
  UNION ALL Select 5 UNION ALL Select 6 UNION ALL Select 7 UNION ALL Select 8
  UNION ALL Select 9 UNION ALL Select 10 UNION ALL Select 11 UNION ALL Select 12
), Calendar(N) As (
  SELECT CAST(2010 + y.N AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('00' + Cast(m.N AS VARCHAR), 2)
  FROM   Months m
         CROSS JOIN Months y
)
SELECT RIGHT(c.N, 2) [Month]
     , LEFT(c.N, 4) [Year]
     , SUM(money_per_month) Incomes
FROM   lodgings_Contract lc
       INNER JOIN Calendar c 
                  ON c.N BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), lc.day_begin, 112)
                             AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), lc.day_end, 112)
GROUP BY c.N
```

The calendar `CTE` is small as it's unknown to me for how many year is the real data. If there are many years it is better to create a calendar table in your DB and use it instead of calculate it every time.
The calendar `CTE` return a list of month in the format `yyyyMM`.
In the main query the CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), lc.day_begin, 112) change the `day_begin` to the ISO format `yyyyMMdd` and take only the first six value, so again `yyyyMM`, for example for the id_contract 3 we will have `201412`, the same for the day_end.
If the beginning of the contract is `day_register` change `lc.day_begin` to `lc.day_register`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c881/2) demo

Comment: Thank You it help me alot . This is final part in my project